# loading data to table using angular

Tags: angularjs

I must be missing something here, but why isn't my table loading with data using Ng-table? I tried following a example but it wont work for me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example - example-example105-production</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="test">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<table ng-table="tableParams">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
                <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('test', ['ngTable'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        var data = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 }, {name: "Moroni2", age: 502        }];
        this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data });

  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/UEsEg7zEx1ZNeszgDR04?p=preview)

Comment: You never defined `NgTableParams`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to inject in your controller: `NgTableParams`.

And in dataset change to data as example:

`$scope.table = new NgTableParams({}, {
          data: data
        });`

See your example in plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/b95EjalSTLd70YuB3ZHH?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

2 changes needed here:

1) Put the data on the scope of the controller to share with the view:

```
$scope.data = [{name: 'Mor .....;
```

2) Use the name of the scope variable (data) in the html

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this change controller

```
   $scope.data = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 }, {name: "Moroni2", age: 502        }];

//   this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data });
```

and use

```
   ng-repeat="row in data"
```